# SQL Server Setup failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server 2008

When I am going to installation process I got the following error. Please give me some solution or guidance.Thank you so much.

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\wtbsrbaw.dll' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error code 0x84B10001.

Comment: The question is clearly about SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: This might be of some assistance http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/12/sql-server-2008-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-images/ make sure you are following the steps correctly.